Fit matrix to a line using multiple regression
Given 3 arrays
var x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var x2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
var x3 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];

and the target Sinusoid
y = [
  0.0, 
  0.30901699437494745, 
  0.5877852522924731, 
  0.8090169943749473, 
  0.9510565162951535, 
  1.0, 
  0.9510565162951536, 
  0.8090169943749475, 
  0.5877852522924732, 
  0.3090169943749475
];

created in a similar way
var y = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(o => Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * o);

How do I find weights for each x array so that their combination fits y sinusoid?
According to docs, I can use any of these methods.
var X = new double[,] { x1, x2, x3 };


MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(X, y)
Fit.Polynomial(X, y, 10)
Fit.MultiDim(X, y, intercept: true)
Fit.LinearMultiDim(X, y, o => 0, o => Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * o)
Fit.LinearCombination(X, y, o => 0, o => Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * o)

Questions

Which method is best suited to fit array of arrays to a sin line?
When arrays are combined into matrix, should it be row or column based matrix?

Row based matrix
var X = new double[,] 
{ 
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
}

Column based matrix
var X = new double[,] 
{ 
  {1, 10, 100}, 
  {2, 20, 200}, 
  {3, 30, 300}, 
  {4, 40, 400}, 
  {5, 50, 500}, 
  {6, 60, 600}, 
  {7, 70, 700}, 
  {8, 80, 800}, 
  {9, 90, 900}, 
  {10, 100, 1000}, 
}

